# Bydefault textbox with some value that time we can't change .When i click the button it will allow to edit the previous value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

ANYONE PLEASE HELP ME WITH THIS ?

I want to display one textbox by default with one value the property should be readonly i.e we can't change the value .When i click the button the textbox will allow to edit the textbox  with the previous value .Manily the textbox should be same place

Comment: Have you tried anything ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `disabled="disabled"` and then when you click the button it will allow the edit.

Hope this will help you

**Note** I added the `focusout` to give you an example on how to disable the `textarea` again if you want to

```js
$('#edit').click(function() {
  $('textarea').attr("disabled", false)
})

$('textarea').focusout(function() {
  $('textarea').attr("disabled", true)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea disabled="disabled">click on the button to edit me</textarea>
<button id="edit">allow edit</button>
```

Comment: Happy to help, feel free to upvote this answer if it helped you, and remember to mark it as answer if it solved your problem

Answer (score 0):

```
<body>
    <input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname" value="bipin" readonly="readonly">
    <button onclick="changeValue()">Change value</button>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function changeValue(){
    $("#firstname").attr("readonly", false);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you wanted to make your textbox works like "Read-only" control. Similar to "Label".

I would suggest you to use Jquery to disable the textbox on click of the button by using something like below:

> $("#textbox1").attr("disabled", "disabled");

You can also use CSS to disable the textbox. Please refer the below link:

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_disabled.asp

Thanks.